# Ssh connection to matlab GUI (using screen)

Tags: matlab, ssh, gnu-screen

Can I connect to matlab GUI remotely via ssh and "screen" simultaneously?
Using commands ssh, "screen" and "maltlab -nodesktop" seem to work without graphic interface ,but I need GUI to use specific toolbox.
And I need to disconnect and reconnect it later, because the process takes long time.

My environment is :
Server (matlab) - linux ubuntu
Client - mac osx
 Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you need to run SSH with X11 forwarding (I think OSX already has an X Server on the client). See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so - your best bet is probably a remote desktop solution.

https://www.nomachine.com/ is the first coming to my mind...